# getting 403 error when updating label with gmail api

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I am updating the label of a message. I get a 403 error as you can see below.

```
 if (!emailInfoResponse.LabelIds.Contains(SEND4PROCESSING))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("PROCESS ALERT  " + subject);
                        ModifyMessageRequest mods = new ModifyMessageRequest();
                        List<String> labelsToAdd = new List<String>()
                        {
                            SEND4PROCESSING
                        };
                        mods.AddLabelIds = labelsToAdd;
                        //  mods.RemoveLabelIds = labelsToRemove;
                        service.Users.Messages.Modify(mods, myemail, message.Id).Execute();


                    }
```

full code @ [full code here and exception @ line 134](https://codeshare.io/ax11AN)

```
    Google.GoogleApiException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Insufficient Permission [403]
Errors [
    Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]
  Source=Google.Apis
  StackTrace:
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ParseResponse>d__31.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at IBTrading.GmailQuickstart..ctor() in C:\Users \Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\IBTrading\GmailQuickstart.cs:line 134
   at IBTrading.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users \Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\IBTrading\Program.cs:line 14
```

i remembed to setup the update permission as you can see in the screenshot below.[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Sounds like a problem with scopes

Line 22 in your code is

```php
static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom };
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify#auth) for `Users.messages: modify` specifies:

> This request requires authorization with at least one of the following
>   scopes:
>
> Scope
>
> https://mail.google.com/
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify

Also be aware that after you changed the scopes from

```
GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly
```

you  need to delete you previous credentials / token file.